# NullpointerException when using paintComponent method in java

Tags: java, image, paintcomponent

I;m trying to draw an image of a player that i just took off google images. So far nothing is shown when i run my code as i'm making a game. I get the nullpointer exception saying something is wrong with my imageicon and my paintCOmponent method.

THis is the class which has the errors.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D gc = (Graphics2D) g;
    gc.drawImage(getPlayerImg(),row,column, this);
}
public void draw(Graphics2D g2d){
    g2d.drawImage(getPlayerImg(),row,column, this);
}
public Image getPlayerImg(){
     ImageIcon d = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("me.jpg"));
     return d.getImage();
}
```

I also have another class which calls the paintComponent method. I thought this class would be the code for making the image appear since it calls an object from the above class.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        System.out.println("ok");
        c.draw(g2d);
        System.out.println("painted");
        c.setVisible(true);
    }
```

None of the println are printed out on the screen. I don't know what to do :(. The first class has to do with making the map and the second class calls the methods from the first class and makes it. I can't show too much though.

Comment: but doesn't my variable d contain the image that i want to draw so it's not null?

Comment: The most likely cause is `getPlayerImg` is returning a `null` value.  Instead of the loops you seem to jumping through, use `ImageIO.read` to read the image, it will throw an exception if the image can't be read for some reason, but will also block until the image is fully read - so don't do it from within a paint method

Comment: Also, don't call `super.paint` from within `paintComponent`, you'll get yourself into a `StackOverflowException`

Comment: I took out the code and just used the ImageIO.read and it returns no error so it must mean it gets the image o.o

Comment: We'd more context before we'd be able to help you further

Comment: like what? All i know is once i add the paintComponent method my map disappears and will only show after i lose the game

Comment: A runnable example which demonstrates your problem perhaps

Comment: umm how would i do that?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)